# Merging two JSON files with a dominant file that overrides values

Tags: c#, json, merge

I want to merge my JSONs into one while dominant one overwriting values.

Example:

Subordinate JSON:

```json
{
    "test": {
        "test1": true,
        "test2": {
            "test3": [1, 2, 3]
        }
    }
}
```

Dominating JSON:

```json
{
    "test": {
        "test2": null,
        "test3": "string"
    },
    "test2": "newValue"
}
```

Merge result:

```json
{
    "test": {
        "test1": true,
        "test2": null,
        "test3": "string"
    },
    "test2": "newValue"
}
```

With which command can I do it **easily**?

Comment: Given that the two files do not seem follow the same model you will likely need to write your own merge code. Json serialization libraries typically allow you to traverse the json-tree and apply whatever logic you want.

Comment: Ok thanks, ill try implement my own merger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the `Newtonsoft.Json` lib.

You can use the `JObject.Merge` method to combine two JSON objects into one, and specify how to handle the values that are not present in both objects.

Here is a sample code that shows how to do son:

```cs
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

JObject sub = JObject.Parse(@"{ ““test””: { "“test1"”: true, "“test2"”: { ““test3"”: [1, 2, 3] } } }”);

JObject dom = JObject.Parse(@"{ ““test””: { "“test2"”: null, "“test3"”: ““string”” }, ““test2"”: ““newValue”” }”);

// Merge the two JSONs using Merge method 
JObject merged = dom.Merge(sub, new JsonMergeSettings() {  = MergeArrayHandling.Keep, ReplaceNullValuesWith = null });

// Convert the result to string for visualization:
string result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(merged);

// Print the result Console.WriteLine(result);
// output:
// { “test”: { “test1”: true, “test2”: null, “test3”: “string” }, “test2”: “newValue” }
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @Ariel Szmerla for giving answer, but look's like its kindly obsolete.
For C#10 and Newtonsoft.Json v13.0.3 i used this code:

```
        JObject sub = JObject.Parse(@"{ ""test"": { ""test1"": true, ""test2"":  15, ""test3"": { ""test4"": [1, 2, 3] } } }");

        JObject dom = JObject.Parse(@"{ ""test"": { ""test2"": 16, ""test3"": ""string"" }, ""test5"": ""newValue"" }");

        JObject merged;
        {
            merged = (JObject)sub.DeepClone();
            merged.Merge(dom, new JsonMergeSettings() {MergeNullValueHandling = MergeNullValueHandling.Merge, MergeArrayHandling = MergeArrayHandling.Replace});
        }
        
        return merged.ToObject<T>();
```